Formula to find row in which two columns have the needed value, then return what is in a third column
I need help working out a formula.
In the table below, I need a way to find what the status is for a specific venue at a specific time. So for example, if I wanted to know what the status was of McDonalds at 3PM, I need a formula that finds the row in which the venue is 'McDonalds' and the time is '3PM', then returns the status, which in this case would be 'reserved'.
I feel like I'm circling the answer but I can't work out how to make it work.



Venue
Time
Status




McDonalds
2PM
Open


McDonalds
3PM
Reserved


McDonalds
4PM
Sold


Burger King
2PM
Open


Burger King
3PM
Open


Burger King
4PM
Sold


Taco Bell
2PM
Reserved


Taco Bell
3PM
Open


Taco Bell
4PM
Reserved



I've been looking at If/And statements, xlookups, and index/Match (which I'm not very good at), but I haven't been able to crack it. I keep getting spill errors.

Feel free to post your trials also, never mind if it doesn't work as expected.

You need FILTER() function.
=FILTER(C2:C10,(A2:A10=E2)*(B2:B10=F2))

XLOOKUP() should also work like-
=XLOOKUP(1,(A2:A10=E2)*(B2:B10=F2),C2:C10,"")



Upvoted for not using =XLOOKUP("Mcdonalds" & "3PM",A2:A10 & B2:B10,C2:C10) :)

And another version using index() with match():
with unique() to get lists as well as a helper column:

Also used data validation to pick venue and time.
In cell D2:
B2&" "&A2

In cell I3:
INDEX(C2:C10,MATCH(H3&" "&F3,D2:D10,0))


Just to clarify, you don't need a helper column to use INDEX and MATCH solution if you use it as array formula. You can do =INDEX(C2:C10,MATCH(F2&G2,A2:A10&B2:B10,0)) as array formula and it will work

The formula in cell H18: =TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IF((A$18:A$26=F18)*(B$18:B$26=G18),C$18:C$26,""))
Advantage that if there are more status for the same venue and time all are displayed.

